# How to loop through array and do action if two things match

Tags: java, android

After hours of figuring out how to go about changing colours for generated numbers here

```
for (int rolls = 0; rolls < 4 +temp; rolls++) {
            value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
            //Test if numbers generated are correct
            builder.append(value + " ");
            textTest.setText(builder.toString());               
            NumbersArray[rolls] = value;
            System.out.println(NumbersArray[rolls]);
```

I managed to do it, now, I have a problem that all of them change colour at the same time, how can I do this so the first number generated lights up first, waits few seconds then next generated number changes color?
Maybe I'm going about this wrong because all colors change even if that color is not generated

```
            if (rolls == 1) {
                red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                //Wait t amount of time here
                red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000")); /* Changes Color  */
                    }
                },3*100 /*  millisecond  to wait */);
            }
            else if (rolls == 2) {
                yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF000"));
                yellow.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7F7500"));
                    }
                }, 3 * 100);
            }
            else if (rolls == 3) {
                green.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0FFF00"));
                green.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        green.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF087D00"));
                    }
                }, 3 * 100 );
            }
            else  {
                blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
                blue.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00007D"));
                    }
                }, 3 * 100 );
            }
```

Whole for loop:

```
 for (int rolls = 0; rolls < 2 +temp; rolls++) {
            value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
            builder.append(value + " ");
            textTest.setText(builder.toString());
            NumbersArray[rolls] = value;
            System.out.println(NumbersArray[rolls]);


            if (value == 1) {
                red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000"));
                   }
                },3000);
            }
            else if (value == 2) {
                yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF000"));
                yellow.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7F7500"));
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
            else if (value == 3) {
                green.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0FFF00"));
                green.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        green.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF087D00"));
                    }
                }, 3000 );
            }
            else  {
                blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
                blue.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00007D"));
                    }
                }, 3000 );
            }
```

Comment: The condition checking code is inside for loop only?

Comment: Yes, it is. is that right or wrong?

Comment: Can you post the whole for loop?

Comment: I fixed a bit that only numbers generated change color, now I  have to figure out how to change color one after another

Comment: It happens like that because the for loop is not paused anywhere.

Comment: How can I pause the loop? I tried thread.sleep but it didnt work for me unless I was doing it wrong

Comment: You can't use Thread.sleep because we cant make main thread sleep.

Comment: What should I use to pause the loop so?

Comment: Find the below answer and it will do your stuff.

Comment: Let me know, whether you find any issue.

Comment: I get an error on `new Handler();` that Handler is abstract and cannot be initialised

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for giving pause for temporary times to the content updating and checking conditions.Here the handler will run the runnable for the first time without any time delay, after that it will take 1000 ms in between to update the content and will run like a loop.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (rolls < 2 + temp) {
                    rolls++;
                    //Do your stuff here
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
```

Comment: @TroubleSome We dont need to take for loop.

Comment: @TroubleSome you need to import android.os.Handler.

Comment: I did import that but I still get the error that it's abstract and cannot be initialised.

Comment: @troublesome give me some time and i will explain

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate the help